# Html form elements disappear after retrieving JSON data using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I know this is probably something simple, but I can't figure it out. When I load the page, I see a flash of my text area box and the button and then the json data is diplayed on the page, replacing it. Why are the other elements disappearing?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="chat">
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $.getJSON("process.php?jsoncallback=?", function(data){
                    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                        document.write(data[x].username);
                        document.write(': ');
                        document.write(data[x].comment);
                        document.write('<br/><br/>');
                    }
                });
            });
            </script>
        </div>

        <div id="send">
            <textarea id="send_text"></textarea>
            <button>Send</button>
        </div>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: because document.write is replacing everything on the page, instead,m target an element and update it with the data, such as $("#jsonData").html(data[x].username);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's what `document.write` does. I'm guessing you actually want to append your content somewhere. You can use the jQuery [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) methods to set the content of an element.

What is actually happening when you call `document.write`? The [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write) explains it well:

> Writing to a document that has already loaded without calling
>   document.open() will automatically perform a document.open call.

And the page on [`document.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.open) tells us this:

> If a document exists in the target, this method clears it

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using document.write, which will overwrite all the page content and in any event offers crap performance compared to the equivalent jQuery methods. It would also be easier to use $.each for looping the JSON result e.g.

```
<div id="chat"></div>
<script type="text/javascript>
     $(function() {
          $.getJSON("process.php?jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
               $.each(data, function() {
                     $("#chat").append(this.username + ": " + this.comment);
               });
          });
      });
</script>
```